# specifically fill a combo box in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

I have added a combo box in a specific column in the grid and i have populated it. So when the grid is filled the combo box are also filled with predefined values. I am trying to filter specific rows like this: if column 1 has value 'one' I need to populate the combo box with "one", "two" and "three", otherwise my combo box needs to have the predefined values. In a sense I need to access the control in each row. Is this possible somehow?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: are you looking for AutoComplete..? for example if you type in FL the list should filter down to Flint, Flow, Flower.. ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to help you ask this more clearly, but i dont understand what you need

Answer (score 1):

I think i understand what you want, you can fill your comboBox in the form load event of the data grid events and you can access the combobox for each row in your grid

```
private void form1_load(object sender, EventArg e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
     {
         DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = gridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
         if (gridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "one")
         {
             cell.Items.Clear();
             cell.Items.Add("one");
             cell.Items.Add("two");
             cell.Items.Add("three");
         }
     }
}
```

I assumed that the column with the comboBox has index 5 in the grid.

Comment: Can this be done by looping in the grid? I am asking because all the data are dumped by a DataSource.

Comment: Yes sure
after you fill the grid or data source you can loop on the grid and do the same

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Auto Complete try setting the following values of the ComboBox Prorperties

```
1. Set AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend
2. Set AutoCompleteSource = ListItems
```

if you are binding from a DataSource then you can set that in the Code Behind